# why my load more button after ajax load requires another click on it before it hides even if there is nothing left to load

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

All I am trying to hide the button when there is nothing left to load.
Everything is working fine, after clicking on it it ajax loads fine appends the the dom fine.

Only thing is after loading the last page. Button still sits on the page as there is nothing more left to load. And when I click on it, then it hides.

I want it to hide automatically when there is nothing left to load. Please suggest. Thank you

```
<style>
    .load_more{background: url(/skin/frontend/enterprise/ubt_new/images/drop_down.png) no-repeat;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 75px;padding-bottom: 15px;}
</style>


<div class="resultsblock" style="float: left;width: 728px;margin-bottom: 30px;">
<div class="results"></div>
<div class="clear:left;"></div>
<button class="load_more" style="margin-left: 305px;margin-top: -4px;display: none;" id="load_more_button"></button>
<div class="animation_image" style="display:block;"><img src=""> Loading...</div>
</div>
```

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {  

    var track_click = 1; //track user click on "load more" button, righ now it is 0 click

    var total_pages = <?php echo $this->totalPages(); ?>;
    console.log(total_pages);

    jQuery('.results').load("http://www.ubt.com/index.php/featured/course/index", {'p':track_click}, function() {track_click++;
    jQuery('.animation_image').hide();
    jQuery(".load_more").show();
    console.log(track_click);


}); //initial data to load


    jQuery(".load_more").click(function (e) { //user clicks on button

  jQuery(this).hide(); //hide load more button on click

        if(track_click <= total_pages) //user click number is still less than total pages
        {

        jQuery('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image
            console.log(track_click);
            //post page number and load returned data into result element
            jQuery.post('http://www.ubt.com/index.php/featured/course/index',
                        {'p': track_click}, function(data) {

                jQuery(".load_more").show(); //bring back load more button

                jQuery(".results").append(data); //append data received from server

                //scroll page smoothly to button id
                jQuery("html, body").animate({scrollTop: jQuery("#load_more_button").offset().top}, 500);

                //hide loading image
                jQuery('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received

                track_click++; //user click increment on load button
             console.log(track_click);

            }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?
                alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error
                jQuery(".load_more").show(); //bring back load more button
                jQuery('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received
            });

// I believe here relies the problem, even when the track click is more than the condition
// It's skipping this check and not hiding it.
// It hides after recieveing the last click which is not requied as there is nothing to load



            if(track_click >= total_pages-1) //compare user click with page number
            {
                console.log(total_pages-1);
                //reached end of the page yet? disable load button
                jQuery(".load_more").hide();

            }
         }

        });


});

// finsihing for the ajax to finish and run stuff on that ajax loaded stuff
// It has nothing  to do with the button, just copying in case

jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    if(jQuery('.prod').length != 0) {
        jQuery(".prod").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).find(".prod_title").hide();
        jQuery(this).find(".prod_desc").fadeIn();
    },function(){        
    jQuery(this).find(".prod_desc").fadeOut(); 

    jQuery(this).find(".prod_title_wrap").show();
    jQuery(this).find(".prod_title").show();
    });
}

});



</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your track_click increment is in post,so it's async, whereas your comparison happens immediately after the post trigger (not execution), so you don't have a chance to test at the right time.
move your comparison inside the post result handling...

Comment: but isn't the page loads from top top bottom? As in my case comparison function is right at the bottom. I've checked your solution yet.

Comment: Thanks mate !!! It works. But would you please explain what I have asked in the comment above?

Comment: The page does load from top to bottom, however, some actions are performed within the execution stream, and others get a separate execution stream.  For example, async jquery post requests get a separate thread that executes the post (unless requested to be sync), and the triggering thread continues to the next command without waiting for the post to end.